# I am reading from an external file in java that consists of strings. I am trying to cut the string short and add them to an array called strings

Tags: java

```
private Scanner c;

public void openFile3() {
    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>(7);
    try {
        c = new Scanner(new File("IRStudents.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }
    while (c.hasNextLine()) {
        list3.add(c.nextLine());
    }
    String[] arrayThree = list3.toArray(new String[list3.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(arrayThree);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayThree));
    int size = arrayThree.length;
    String [] names;
    for(int j = 0; j<size;j++) {
        String word = arrayThree[j];
        String newWord = word.substring(6, 15);
```

I am only trying to put the characters of the `String` from 6-15 into a `String` array called names. I have already put them into an array called `arrayThree` now I want to put the shortened versions of the `String` into another array called names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] names = new String[size];

for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
  names[j] = arrayThree[j].substring(6, Math.min(15, arrayThree[j].length()));
}
```